# Ubuntu VM on Azure

Tags: azure

I have lost some very important files on Azure temporary folder /dev/sdb1/mnt
Is there anyways I can recover it.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** way to recover any data from the temporary drive.  Every VM contains a temporary disk, which is not a managed disk. The temporary disk provides short-term storage for applications and processes and is intended to only store data such as page or swap files. Data on the temporary disk **may be lost** during a maintenance event or when you redeploy a VM. During a standard reboot of the VM, the data on the temporary drive should persist. However, there are cases where the data may not persist, such as moving to a new host. Therefore, any data on the temp drive should not be data that is critical to the system.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/managed-disks-overview

Answer (score 0):

Temporary disk data always lose when you are going to reboot the server so there is no way to recover any type of the store in temporary disk after reboot.

**Is there a way to recover data from the temporary drive?**
There is no way to recover any data from the temporary drive.

**What should I do to store data that I cannot afford to lose?**
You can attach a data disk to the virtual machine to store data that you cannot afford to lose. OS disk and data disks are persistent storage. More information on data disks [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/attach-a-disk/).

Find more understanding on temporary drive.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2013/12/06/understanding-the-temporary-drive-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines/